# $.getJSON cross domain

Tags: php, getjson

How do i $.getJSON from cross domain ? this is my code :

```
function loadPrice(){
    pid = $('#prod').val();
    bid = $('#bank').val();
    cc = 2;
    if(pid){
      if(bid == 5 || bid == 6){
        cc = 4
      }
      var d=new Date();
      var n=d.valueOf();
      $('#cc').val(cc);
      $('#price').text('Loading..').removeClass('priceerror');
      $.getJSON('http://www.domain.com/price.php?pid='+pid+'&cc='+cc+'&tm='+n,function(data){
        $('#price').text(data.symbol+' '+data.price);
        $('#priceval').val(data.value);
      }).error(function(){$('#price').text('Error!').addClass('priceerror')});
    }
  }
```

Error message :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://www.domain.com/price.php?pid=601&cc=2&tm=1413248654388. This
>   can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling
>   CORS.

Any idea ?

Comment: "_This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS._"

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cross domain policy on the remote server.  If you don't have access to it yourself, you'll have to get the administrator of the remote server to assist you.

You can learn about setting up the crossdomain.xml file here:  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-a-guide-to-cross-domain-policy-files--active-3832